# What are some good ways to retain mutiple UICollectionView's scroll position within a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Every-time an `UIViewController` swiped away from current page, it will be destroyed.

If the `UIViewController`  swiped back again as current page, it will be re-created again.

[image]

However, as you can see from the screen recording, the scroll position of `UICollectionView` is "lost" every-time we swipe back as current page.

I was wondering, what are some good ways, to retain mutiple UICollectionView's scroll position within a UIPageViewController?

1. Does iOS provide any underlying framework for us to achieve so?
2. If we need to do it manually, when we should save the scroll position of `UICollectionView` in a global variable? `viewDidUnload` seems not being called anymore.
3. When is the good time to restore the scroll position? `viewDidLoad`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Does iOS provide any underlying framework for us to achieve so?

Not really, this will need to be handled manually. Let's say you would introduce some kind of delegate protocol that would be implemented by the root controller.

```swift
protocol ScrollPositionDelegate: class {
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didChangeScrollPosition point: CGPoint)
}
```

Then all of the child views would keep weak reference to the delegate

```swift
weak var delegate: ScrollPositionDelegate?
```

And call it whenever the position changes. In root You could identify the which view called the delegate method by using `tag` property on the collectionView (you would need to set it first within the child screen)

```swift
extension RootViewController: ScrollPositionDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didChangeScrollPosition point: CGPoint) {
        switch collectionView.tag {
        case 1:
            // store scroll position for screen 1
        default:
            return
        }
        // or simply
        scrollPosition[collectionView.tag] = point
        // obviously you would need storage like `scrollPosition: [Int: CGPoint]`
    }
}
```

> 2. If we need to do it manually, when we should save the scroll position of UICollectionView in a global variable? viewDidUnload seems not being called anymore.

You can either save the values when the `viewWillDisappear` or when the collection view delegate calls `scrollViewDidScroll`

> 3. When is the good time to restore the scroll position? viewDidLoad?
>    `viewDidLoad` is good idea to start but there is no guarantee that the layout will be ready. You could try again at `viewWillAppear` or after you call `collectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: I give a quick try by calling `collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, y: 100)` followed by `collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. But didn't observe any scrolling effect. Not sure why...

Comment: try `setContentOffset()` on a collectionView

Comment: and you want to make sure you are scrolling **after** the view **Did** layout its subviews. for example `viewWillAppear`

Comment: sorry I did mislead you with `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, this method does not exist. I actually meant `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Thanks. The following code snippet work for my case - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/41d56a68ef6eddfa76a13a87d7515851

Comment: great to hear that.